# want to import exported xml file

Tags: xml, phpmyadmin, wamp

I have exported a single table as xml file from wamp phpmyadmin and i want to import again its data in mysql table... I have tried all the suggested solutions on this awesome portal. but its not working for me. please guide me.MY exported table data as xml file is as follows `

### - http://www.phpmyadmin.net

- Host: 127.0.0.1
- Generation Time: Mar 08, 2016 at 10:50 AM
- Server version: 5.6.17
- PHP Version: 5.5.12
  -->

CREATE TABLE `pppcenter` (
                  `NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                  `ADDRESS` text NOT NULL,
                  `DISTRICT` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                  `CONTACT` varchar(100) NOT NULL
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

```
<!--
- Database: 'abc'
-->
<database name="abc">
    <!-- Table pppcenter -->
    <table name="pppcenter">
        <column name="NAME">abc</column>
        <column name="ADDRESS">xyzabc</column>
        <column name="DISTRICT">abc</column>
        <column name="CONTACT">123456798</column>
    </table>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

this can used error is occured but data is inserted in tabel pppcenter.

First To create the database in Your phpmyadmin and import the file its work.

```
<!--
- Database: 'abc'
-->
<pma_xml_export version="1.0">
<database name="practical">
    <!-- Table pppcenter -->
    <table name="pppcenter">
        <column name="NAME">abc</column>
        <column name="ADDRESS">xyzabc</column>
        <column name="DISTRICT">abc</column>
        <column name="CONTACT">123456798</column>
    </table>
</database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .